# How can we train parallel layers in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, torch

What is the best way to plug layers in parallel/serial in Tensorflow, much like the concept of Containers in Torch (https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/master/doc/containers.md)?

My use-case is to learn two LSTM sequences (in encoder-decoder environment) simultaneously from the same input based on the combined cost of the two sequences.

Comment: Could you precise which functionality of Containers you need (Sequential, Parallel, Concat...) or write a simple example in Torch?

Comment: So I basically need a kind of parallel layer where I can learn two sequences simultaneously from single input. The error from both sequence is combined to do the back propagation.

Comment: I don't understand very well your model, but if you just add the loss from the two LSTM sequences, the gradients will update both weights simultaneously.